# angular application breaking on installing a package

Tags: angular, npm, package, npm-install, signalr-2

I have cloned an existing angular project. I did `ng serve` and the application is running fine. I wanted to install signalR package. I have executed

```
npm install @aspnet/signalr –-save
```

The package is installed successfully. But then when I run `ng serve`, the project has failed to compile with errors

```
ERROR in ./src/app/PackageAdd.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'json-diff' in 'C:\Users\Web\src\app\components'
ERROR in ./src/app/components/Update.modal.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'json-diff' in 'C:\Users\Web\src\app\components'
ERROR in ./src/app/components/CreateEdit.component.ts
```

So I wanted to revert back to the initial state and tried to uninstall the package. I tried with

```
npm uninstall @aspnet/signalr
```

and then did `ng serve` but still see the same errors. I am not sure what to do now. How do I revert back to the initial state where the application is getting compiled successfully and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be an error from Signalr. From the error you've provivded, I'm guessing there's a `json-diff` npm package being used in your project (look in `package.json` for it).

If it's not supposed to be there (check the original code), remove the code related to `json-diff` from the `Update.modal.ts` and `CreateEdit.component.ts` files.

If it's supposed to be there, make sure it's listed in package.json (otherwise, install it). If it's already installed, delete the `package-lock.json` file and the `node_modules` folder, and run `npm install` again.

If everything fails, and you just want to revert to the original branch code, run `git clean -fd && git reset --hard` (WARNING: this will remove all un-pushed local changes that you had done to the branch as well as new files that are not tracked by git). Confirm that the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder are deleted in your project, and run `npm install`